# Get a count of records using multiple tables

Tags: sql

Hi I have a table deliveries

```
delivery_id | remarks | Fid
         1    IsTicket  001
         2    NoTicket  002
```

And a Second table

```
Assn | Fid 
CSCPA  001
PSCPA  002
```

How can i get a count of `delivery_id` per `Fid` based on `Assn` is i provide assn as a parameter

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
select
  t2.assn, count(*)
from deliveries d
join table2 t2 on t2.fid = d.fid
group by t2.assn
```

For a single association you can so:

```
select
  count(*)
from deliveries d
join table2 t2 on t2.fid = d.fid
where t2.assn = ? -- replace ? with your parameter
```

Comment: I want to provide association as a parameter

Answer (score 1):

You want an aggredated query with an `INNER JOIN` between both tables, and a `WHERE` clause that filters on `assn`.

```
SELECT d.fid, COUNT(*)
FROM deliveries d
INNER JOIN table t on t.fid = d.fid
WHERE t.assn = ?
GROUP BY d.fid
```

Just replace the `?` with the `assn` you want to filter with.

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
select a.delivery_id,a.Fid,b.Assn,count(delivery_id) from deliveries a,2ndtablename b
where a.Fid=b.Fid and
b.Assn=:Assn 
group by a.delivery_id,a.Fid,b.Assn;
```